# Storing String / Text values over 500 Chars with and without GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I made a GAE-Project with JPA2 for db access. I store some Strings which are more than 500 Characters, so I use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text.

I got an interface Script.java which defines the value as String, and an ScriptImpl.java which has internally a Text member, and converts for getting and setting.

Because one requirement of the project is, that it is still able tu run on an simple tomcat with a database behind. So it must be possible to run inside and outside the google environment.

Is there some realistic way to implement my application so I can switch to a normal tomcat environment (e.g. via a spring configuration to use different beans...).

What else do I have to pay attention to to make this work in both environments and how do I take care of the parts that are seamed thight to GAE?

> **Update:** So far I found the following critic issues: Google User Service & Login Process, Text Class in Domain Models, Wicket-GAE-Initializer (since I use Wicket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE has it's own proprietary API. If you wrote application using this API then if you want to move off of the GAE you have two options:

1. Rewrite your code, obviously.
2. Use a API wrapper that implements GAE API but runs on other platforms. An example of such wrappers are [AppScale](http://www.appscale.com/) and [CapeDwarf](http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf). AppScale is older and probably more mature and supports both Java and Python. Also it supports more platforms (private servers + clouds). OTOH, CapeDwarf is targeted at JBossAS7, so it's probably better fit if you use that server (or OpenShift cloud). Also I guess you can expect better support from a mature open-source leader such as RedHat.

Answer (score 1):

While in theory it might be possible to wrap GAE functionality and then delegate it to either app engine or your "normal" environment it's probably a lot of effort.

Possibly another approach would be easier.  Are you aware of CapeDwarf?

[JBoss CapeDwarf](http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf)

> Deploy and run your Java App Engine applications on your own private
>   JBoss Application Server (AS7) cluster or on RedHat’s OpenShift cloud.
>
> JBoss CapeDwarf is an implementation of the Google App Engine API,
>   which allows applications to be deployed on JBoss Application Servers
>   without modification. Behind the scenes, CapeDwarf uses existing JBoss
>   APIs such as Infinispan, JGroups, PicketLink, HornetQ and others.

If it really needs to be "simple tomcat with a database" then more information or constraints will be helpful to know.